# Android slow USB transfer

Tags: android, usb

I transfer 20MB of data between an Android device and another device via USB using bulk transfer. Everything works ok, but it needs up to 10s to transmit the necessary set. The problem is, that the transfer is splitted into several reads (> 600)

while (r >= 1) { r = connection.bulkTransfer(epbulkin, bytes_p, 64000, 1000);

Even if I try to use a larger buffer of 64000 bytes or more, only 32k is used. I know, that there is a limit of pipe size in Linus Kernel.

How can I overcome this limit in Android app to improve the transfer speed ? If not possible inside Android, can it be done with native C-code from Android ?  Are there other optons to improve transfer    rate ?

Comment: you might need to update the read/write logic in source, there's a file that contains source of it. It is highly optimised considering all test cases, still if you wish, look into sdcard.c file in android source branch

Comment: how should I update read/write logic in source ?